# Copy.com: How to move or copy files from web folders via the web interface

Tags: online-storage

I have a free 15-Giga account with Copy.com. Once I have uploaded files, I am unable to move or copy them among the cloud folders.

Any help?

Comment: Accourding to https://www.copy.com/ Copy.com will be discontinued on May 1, 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a missing feature for the web application that now has been added.

You can now *drag and drop items just like you would in an ordinary  file manager*.

Considering the usability, the extraordinary amount of free gigabytes, the public APIs, to me [Copy.com](http://www.copy.com) is now the best free service around.